# Generic Calls to stored procedure for data download from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, generics, stored-procedures

I would like to call a number of stored procedures based on a set of user selection and return data that the user will download. Each stored procedure has a different set of parameter list and type. Those parameter will be exposed through a web page as form elements.
My question is mainly to have other ideas of a generic mechanism for calling the stored procedures from C# regardless of the type of the parameters.

I 'm currently thinking of configuring an xml file that will define how stored procedures can be called and based on the parameter type list dynamically parse the input and call the given stored procedure.

I would be really happy to have any other ideas using any other mechanism available in the .Net framework. I'm not sure if there are better ways.

Many thanks in advance
b

Comment: I like the idea.  Make sure when you add the parameters to the command you include the type like DbType.Date.  You will need switch statement to convert the stored XML type to the Data Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to do it, however I'm not so sure that they are better.

One way is to use [`SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) method to populate your [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) dynamically.

The main advantage of using this method is that you don't need to keep the parameters list in another place besides the stored procedure itself, making your maintenance much easier. Also, it makes your code shorter and cleaner.

The disadvantage is that it requires a database call for each stored procedure, which might be a little slower than parsing an XML file.

Note the remarks section on the DeriveParameters MSDN page I've linked to:

> **DeriveParameters** overwrites any existing parameter information for the SqlDbCommand.
>   **DeriveParameters** requires an additional call to the database to obtain the information. If the parameter information is known in advance, it is more efficient to populate the parameters collection by setting the information explicitly.
>   You can only use DeriveParameters with stored procedures. You cannot use DeriveParameters with extended stored procedures. You cannot use DeriveParameters to populate the SqlParameterCollection with arbitrary Transact-SQL statements, such as a parameterized SELECT statement.

The way to use it is very simple:

```
SqlCommand cmd;
Using(SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", Con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    Con.Open();
    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
    Con.Close();
}
```

Once you've executed this code, cmd.Parameters will contain all of the parameters ready to use, all you will have to do is set the value for them.

I would recommend to create a method that will encapsulate this code and get the SqlCommend as a parameter. Also, you will probably want to create a method that will return the input control most suited for each parameter (i.e `DatePicker` for `SqlDBType.Date`, `TextBox` for `SqlDBType.Varchar` etc`).

Comment: This is an eye opener. This is the kind of solution i was looking for. I still need a way to populate the form elements based on the parameters required by each stored procedure but i think having an xml file store these information will close the gap. many thanks

Comment: First, I'm glad I could help. Second, why would you need an xml file to store information about what element is suited for what kind of control? There are not that many parameter types, and not that many controls. I would create a hard coded method to decide the kind of input control based on the parameter datatype if I was in your situation.

Comment: Correct but having just to write a new stored procedure and add the definition in some sort of configuration file is part of the requirement for the task. The Code should not be built when new report  need to be added. Hope this makes sense. Cheers

Comment: It makes sense, but not a lot of it :-). giving the fact that there are not that many different data types in sql, and most of them would be a group or 2 or more that will need the same input (i.,e for all string types a simple textbox will suffice), I don't see a reason not to create the code to translate the data type to it's relevant input for each of the options in advance.